# How can I show a "tr" tags content when I click a button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-app

I am creating a chrome app and I need part of a table to show up when I click a button.

I have looked at various and answers but I keep getting an error from chrom when I click the button/

Here is my JavaScript:

```
    document.getElementById("newpull").style.visibility = "visible";
}
);
window.onload = function () {
        document.getElementById("newpull").style.visibility = "hidden";
};
```

And my HTML:

```
 <button id="click" style="float; left">Click</button>


<tr class="red" id="newpull">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: You should reproduce the issue described within the question, a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

display block and none on button click

```js
function myFunc() {
  var disp = document.getElementById("newpull").style.display;
  console.log(disp);
  if (disp == 'block') {
    document.getElementById("newpull").style.display = 'none'
  } else {
    document.getElementById("newpull").style.display = 'block'
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="click" style="float; left" onclick="myFunc()">Click</button>
<table>
  <tr id="newpull" style="display:none">
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>abc</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

just put function in script and fire from button click using put this `onclick="showTR()"` in `<button>`

```
<button id="click" style="float: left" onclick="showTR()">Click</button>

<table>
    <tr class="red" id="newpull">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

> this is your script

```
function showTR(){
   document.getElementById("newpull").style.visibility = "visible";
}
window.onload = function () {
   document.getElementById("newpull").style.visibility = "hidden";
};
```

> OR you can also use like this

```
function showTR(){
var status = document.getElementById("newpull").style.visibility ;
  if (status == 'visible') {
     document.getElementById("newpull").style.visibility = "hidden";
  } else {
     document.getElementById("newpull").style.visibility = "visible";
  }
}
window.onload = function () {
   document.getElementById("newpull").style.visibility = "hidden";
};
```